Difference between jsonb type cast and to_jsonb in postgresql
Why do these two queries give different result in postgresql ?
select '{"items":["foo", "bar"]}'::jsonb->'items';

select to_jsonb('{"items":["foo", "bar"]}'::text)->'items';

the first one returns: ["foo", "bar"] and the second one returns [NULL]

Look at the output of to_jsonb(…::text) and it'll become immediately obvious.

The documentation for to_jsonb() says this (emphasis mine):

Converts any SQL value to json or jsonb. Arrays and composites are converted recursively to arrays and objects (multidimensional arrays become arrays of arrays in JSON). Otherwise, if there is a cast from the SQL data type to json, the cast function will be used to perform the conversion; otherwise, a scalar JSON value is produced. For any scalar other than a number, a Boolean, or a null value, the text representation will be used, with escaping as necessary to make it a valid JSON string value.

In other words, it isn't parsing JSON from string, it's creating a JSON string from your text.
select 
    to_jsonb('{"items":["foo", "bar"]}'::text),
    to_jsonb('{"items":["foo", "bar"]}'::text)->'items';




to_jsonb
?column?




"{\"items\":[\"foo\", \"bar\"]}"






First one is assignment, second one is conversion.
First one assigns a type to an unknown constant, the second one converts a constant of an already known text type, to another type.

PostgreSQL treats single-quoted constants as type unknown. When you add ::jsonb, it verifies if the constant is a valid jsonb literal and assigns the type.
It already told you exactly that, which is why you had to add ::text before passing the constant to to_jsonb():
select to_jsonb('{"items":["foo", "bar"]}');


ERROR:  could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown


And once you added ::text, to_jsonb() mapped the whole thing from a plain PostgreSQL text type to JSON internal string type, ignoring what's inside it. -> returned null because the value is now a lonely JSON string, not an object with keys in it, so the path ->'items' isn't valid.
The only valid path in there is no path at all: #>>'{}' (that's an empty array of keys that forms a path with no steps)
select to_jsonb('{"items":["foo", "bar"]}'::text) #>> '{}';




?column?




"{"items":["foo", "bar"]}"



Which is how you can get back your text-type value back out of that JSON.

The clever thing about to_jsonb() is how you can automagically map out your tables to jsonb:
create table test(a text,b boolean, c numeric);
insert into test values ('abc', true, 123.45);

select to_jsonb(test) from test;




to_jsonb




{"a": "abc", "b": true, "c": 123.45}



Which the cast won't do:
select test::jsonb from test;


ERROR:  cannot cast type test to jsonb
LINE 1: select test::jsonb from test;
                   ^


